# Problem with rendering in view_componets in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, view-components

This is the situation in view components:

`app/components/appointments/new_appointment_component.haml`

```
= form_with(model: @appointment, url: appointments_path, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :patient_id, value: @patient.id
  %label= 'Doctor'
  = f.collection_select(:doctor_id, @doctors, :id, :full_name)
  
  %label= 'Date'
  = f.datetime_select :appointment_date, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 1, minute_step: 20
  - if @appointment.errors[:appointment_date].any?
    %p= @appointment.errors[:appointment_date].join(", ")

  = f.submit 'Save'
= link_to "Back", patients_path
```

`app/components/appointments/new_appointment_component.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Appointments::NewAppointmentComponent < ViewComponent::Base

  attr_reader :patient, :doctors, :appointment

  def initialize(patient:, doctors:, appointment:)
    @patient = patient
    @doctors = doctors
    @appointment = appointment
  end  
end
```

And I this controller and method create:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render Appointments::AppointmentsComponent.new(appointments: Appointment.all)
  end

  def new
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    render Appointments::NewAppointmentComponent.new(patient: @patient, doctors: Doctor.all, appointment: Appointment.new)
  end
  
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)

      if @appointment.save
        redirect_to root_path #  root "patients#index"
        #or     render Appointments::AppointmentsComponent.new(appointments: Appointment.all)        
      else        
         render Appointments::NewAppointmentComponent.new(appointment: @appointment, patient: @appointment.patient, doctors: Doctor.all), content_type: "text/html"  
       end    
    
    
  end

  private

  def appointment_params
    params.require(:appointment).permit(:patient_id, :doctor_id, :appointment_date, :price)
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/patients_controller.rb` and `root`

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  include Pagy::Backend
  ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10
  
  def index
    q = Patient.includes(:appointments).all.ransack(params[:q])
    @pagy, @patients = pagy(q.result, items: ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    render Patients::PatientsComponent.new(patients: @patients, pagy: @pagy, q: q)
  end

  def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    render Patients::PatientDetailsComponent.new(patient: @patient)
  end

end
```

and are problems in create method:

1.
when `if @appointment.save` I want to redirect to some other page, but in DOM:
content from `redirect_to root_path`is added below to `body`, and I have content from existing component(`app/components/appointments/new_appointment_component.haml` in body and below this contenct from `root_path`. Why?
[image: Dom Screen]

2)
when is `else` refresh doesn't work and text from validation isn't visible.

What are the best solutions to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

See the layout. It's located at `app/views/layouts/application.haml` if not custom. For debugging purposes, I would start by removing everything and just leaving `= yield` along with the head (js/css files). If that helped, then read the code in the layout file carefully and fix it.